# Zend Framework Invalid controller specified excepection

Tags: zend-framework

Hi I have a problem trying to configure Zend Frame work in test server, I have the project working fine in my local mac computer, I upload all the file to my root html docs in my test server, exactly like I have it in my local, but for some reason I can't found my controllers, the error I have is this

```
An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (MessageBroker)
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/html/magentoreviewsZF/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /var/www/html/magentoreviewsZF/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/html/magentoreviewsZF/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 /var/www/html/magentoreviewsZF/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'MessageBroker',
  'action' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

I have see in other post that changing the RewriteBase in the htaccess do the trick, but don't work for me, also I have the default structure, also the index controller and the error controller works, if I go directly to their path.

so is working is just my MessageBroker controller is not been found, why!, please anybody can point me to the right direction, I really don't know what else to do, thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Iam not sure, but let me guess: Test Server = Windows ? Production = Linux ?

Take care about the filename / classname of your Controller on linux its case sensetive so name you Controller:

```
class MessagebrokerController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{}
```

And your filename: **MessagebrokerController.php**